# Unable to send message from PC and mobilephone using socket communication

Tags: java, android, sockets

this is my task:to connect PC and mobile phone using socket communication.i have a problem in sending the message i type in the socket connection. i use eclipse to run the program from PC to phone. i type in my text on the textbox. when i press the send button, i could not send the text and let it reflect on the phone. the program codes do not have errors anymore. 
this is the link i got for the codes: http://android-er.blogspot.sg/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html

these are my codes with no errors:

```
public class AndroidClient extends Activity {

EditText textOut;
TextView textIn;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.socket_client);

    textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
    Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Socket socket = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket("10.217.137.207", 8888);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
            textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if (socket != null){
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataOutputStream != null){
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataInputStream != null){
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }};
}
```

Comment: Could you add the Logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the code that you are trying to open a socket connection from your device to external device with given IP [10.217.137.207].

This code should work only if you use the ip of device you are testing it on.
Try to use 127.0.0.1

```
dataInputStream.readUTF();
```

will return anything if and only if it is being written from device with IP [10.217.137.207].

If you are using your device's IP address then

```
dataInputStream.readUTF();
```

will return all that you write with

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF()
```

I believe it must be clear.